# How to scale the grpc unary calls

Tags: python, scalability, grpc

I am trying to scale the number of unary grpc calls I can make in a second. I am using a threadpool with futures and for a second, I am making as many calls are possible using the threadpool. After that second is elapsed, I check how many of those calls are finished in the future within the next second. I see that only around 350 futures were completed. It only takes 5ms for the call to return, because the server is not doing anything.

Any suggestions how I can scale that?

Comment: Is the computation inside the `Future` running in Python? If you are using CPython, you will very quickly run into the global interpreter lock being the bottleneck.

Comment: @BobDalgleish. Yeah but my tasks are IO bound. So should it still be an issue?

Comment: Please share the code you are running and please also tell us on what platform (hardware, operating system, Python version, and so forth) you are running that code?